# Pre-Define value for ToAddress When Sending email from Case - Email Action?

Tags: email, case, service-cloud-console, email2case, service

I am working on the on service cloud so it is very important for our agents to send email from case and they always use it to send emails.

For that I have created email action and added this to chatter. Upto here it  is fine. But, The agents wants to send the emails to Contacts. I have set the predefine values of **"ToAddress"** to this formula:

```
IF( Case.ContactEmail != Null, Case.ContactEmail, Case.SuppliedEmail )
```

But, I observed that salesforce takes the `case.SuppliedEmail` even if there is contact linked to Case.

Can you please suggest me workaround for this standard behaviour of salesforce.

Much Thank in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To send the email from action, you don't need to define pre-defined 'ToAdress' field.

By default, it takes contact email id like this way.

[image: Email Publisher]

Comment: I agree with you. It's true. 

But in my case the emails are coming from Email-To-Case and in this case the 'toAddress' is populated by the suppliedEmail. Looking forward for your thought.

Answer (score 0):

> If you use the standard Email Action, You don't need to pre-define the
>   value of ToAddress field whereas if you created a custom case object
>   specific Email Action, You need to Pre-define the value of ToAddress
>   field.

[image]

The below action will be automatically enabled when you enable email-to-case in the org. **To Recipients** field is already pre-defined.

[image]

Now coming to your question,The below formula works well for me.

```
 IF( Case.ContactEmail != Null, Case.ContactEmail, Case.SuppliedEmail )
```

See the screenshot below. It case detail has contact linked with it and it picked the contact email in the action.

[image]

whereas when i delete the contact from Case, It picks the web email as per formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. One think I like to know if the case you created was from web or email2case?

Comment: It has been created from web. I have not created it with email2case.

Comment: yes if it's from email2case then it is picking suppliedemail whatsoever the predefine value.